# Jasmine spyOn javascript getter causing karma to hang

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I'm having some issues using Jasmine to write tests which spy on a Javascript getter. It causes my test suite to hang (using karma + phantomJS) and then ultimately the browser disconnects having never progressed further than the test in question.

A simple example is probably the easiest way to explain (using ES6 transpiled with webpack + babel-loader):

```
class ExampleClass {
    get name() {
        return "My Name";
    }
}
```

In order to change what this get method returns for my test, I am trying the following:

```
describe("example class getter"), function() {
    it("should return blue", function() {
        let exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
        spyOn(exampleClass, 'name').and.returnValue('blue');
        expect(exampleClass.name).toBe('blue');
    });
});
```

This results in the following (where the test in question is my 7th test):

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 8 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.02 secs)
WARN [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 8 DISCONNECTED (10.003 secs / 0.02 secs)
DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
```

spyOn is working for other methods which aren't defined using the get syntax, so I am confident the build pipeline for transpilation is working fine.

Has anyone seen this before, or have any ideas about a fix?

Comment: If you are using Jasmine 2, `.andReturn(value)` has been changed to `.and.returnValue(value)`

Comment: Quite right, I had missed that when typing out this example. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem I'll update the question to have correct code though, thanks.

Comment: Uh, a property that uses a getter is *not a method*. It's just `exampleClass.name === "My Name"`. No functions, no return values visible.

Comment: Also, I'm missing `let exampleClass = new ExampleClass` somewhere?

Comment: let exampleClass = new ExampleClass is missing as I was just highlighting the relevant block from the code, it is higher up in my actual file.

So given that the getters aren't treated as methods, I assume this is in fact impossible then and I'd have to change the methods to be `getName()`

(I've fleshed the code out though, shouldn't omit things when asking questions)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same. Here's the way I've solved this:

```
class Foo {
  get status() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

So mock this Foo for test:

```
class FooMock extends Foo {
  _fakeStatus() {
    return 1;
  }

  get status() {
    return this._fakeStatus();
  }
}
```

And then you use the `FooMock` instead the `Foo`! e.g:

```
it('check the status', () => {
  spyOn(fooInstance, '_fakeStatus').and.returnValue(3);
  expect(fooInstance.status).toBe(3);
}
```

Hope this works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you neglected to invoke the `name` function in your expect call.  Like this:

```
describe("example class getter"), function() {
    it("should return blue", function() {
        let exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
        spyOn(exampleClass, 'name').and.returnValue('blue');
        expect(exampleClass.name()).toBe('blue');
    });
});
```