# How can I spy on a getter property using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I spy on a getter property using jasmine?

```
var o = { get foo() {}, };

spyOn(o, 'foo').and.returnValue('bar'); // Doesn't work.
```

This also does not work AFAICT:

```
spyOn(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'foo'), 'get').and.returnValue('bar');
```

Comment: From discussion on [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338197), you can't. Getters and setters are not treated as standard methods (they don't need to be invoked as functions, for example.)

Comment: Maybe you could just test a result of the retrieved value depending on different object states.

Comment: Based on the comments here, it's apparently not implemented, but it's not theoretically impossible. The reason `spyOn(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'foo'), 'get')` doesn't work is because `spyOn` rewrites the object's property to be a new function that wraps the existing function. Altering the property descriptor object returned by `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` does nothing to alter the actual property. However, you could change Jasmine to detect setter/getters and actually rewrite the property with `defineProperty`. Maybe open a feature request, if it's important to you?

Comment: @apsillers Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/943

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since Jasmine 2.6, this has been possible with [`spyOnProperty`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOnProperty). To spy on the accessors for the `foo` property, do:

```
spyOnProperty(o, 'foo')
```

This allows you to replace the `set` and/or `get` accessor functions for an accessor property with a spy function. You can specify or `set` or `get` only as a third argument:

```
spyOnProperty(o, 'foo', 'get')
```

If you are stuck using an earlier version and cannot upgrade for some reason, you may be able to merge the [pull request that added this feature](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1203) into your local copy of the code.

Comment: Am i right in thinking that this will fail if the `accessor` has not been set as `configurable:true`? Which means you're out of luck if you're trying to spy on a third party accessor where this has not be specified?

Comment: @james I think a non-configurable property (whether accessor-based or a traditional data property) can never be spied on by Jasmine. (I'm not 100% and can't test at the moment, but all spying is based on property replacement.)

Answer (score 29):

In February 2017, they merged a PR adding this feature, they released it in April 2017.

so to spy on getters/setters you use:
`const spy = spyOnProperty(myObj, 'myGetterName', 'get');`
where myObj is your instance, 'myGetterName' is the name of that one defined in your class as `get myGetterName() {}` and the third param is the type `get` or `set`.

You can use the same assertions that you already use with the spies created with `spyOn`.

So you can for example:

```
const spy = spyOnProperty(myObj, 'myGetterName', 'get'); // to stub and return nothing. Just spy and stub.
const spy = spyOnProperty(myObj, 'myGetterName', 'get').and.returnValue(1); // to stub and return 1 or any value as needed.
const spy = spyOnProperty(myObj, 'myGetterName', 'get').and.callThrough(); // Call the real thing.
```

Here's the line in the github source code where this method is available if you are interested.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/7f8f2b5e7a7af70d7f6b629331eb6fe0a7cb9279/src/core/requireInterface.js#L199

Answering the original question, with jasmine 2.6.1, you would:

```
var o = { get foo() {} };
spyOnProperty(o, 'foo', 'get').and.returnValue('bar');
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I think you mean 'spyOnProperty', not 'spyOnAttribute', correct?

Comment: Definitively. I wrote spyOnProperty everywhere else except that last line. I updated the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this if you are unable to use the latest jasmine (2.6.1)

```
const getSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue('bar')
Object.defineProperty(o, 'foo', { get: getSpy });
```

Documentation for defineProperty, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property)

Comment: This solutions comes in handy for scenarios where one has a non-initialized property on a class (e.g [CognitoAuth's](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/e912170bccaf81be1ac1f7dd76ebedba5ac11e04/src/CognitoAuth.js#L27)  [userhandler property](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/e912170bccaf81be1ac1f7dd76ebedba5ac11e04/src/CognitoAuth.js#L47). In this scenario when you inspect the object in console you will not have the property (userhandler in this case). A default initialization of the sort in the answer helps spy the property when actual assignment happens later.

Comment: That's neat! :)

Answer (score 6):

I took inspiration from @apsillers response and wrote the following helper (requires the prop to be configurable as mentioned above)

```
let activeSpies = [];
let handlerInstalled = false;

function afterHandler() {
    activeSpies.forEach(({ obj, prop, descriptor }) => Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor));
    activeSpies = [];
}


export function spyOnGetter(obj, prop) {
    const env = jasmine.getEnv();
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy(`${prop} spy`);
    const copy = Object.assign({}, descriptor, { get: spy });
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, copy);
    activeSpies.push({
        obj,
        prop,
        descriptor,
    });

    if (!handlerInstalled) {
        handlerInstalled = true;
        env.afterEach(() => afterHandler());
    }
    return spy;
}
```

And it can be used like so:

```
import { spyOnGetter } from spyExtra;
it('tests the thing', () => {
    spyOnGetter(myObj, 'myProp').and.returnValue(42);
    expect(myObj.myProp).toBe(42);
});
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Really useful if you cant upgrade the jasmine version!!

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way is to use `spyOnProperty`. It expects 3 properties and you need to pass `get` or `set` as third property.

```
spyOnProperty(o, 'foo', 'get').and.returnValue('bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can spy on getters. The point of a getter is that it acts exactly like a property, so how would jasmine be able to spy on it when it is never called like a function but rather is accessed like a property.

As a workaround, you could have your getter call another function and spy on that instead.

```
var o = {
     _foo: function(){
        return 'foo'; 
     }, 
     get foo(){
        return this._foo();
     }
};

spyOn(o, '_foo').and.returnValue('bar');
```