# How do i mock a global variable for Unit Testing in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a service in my Angular app but I don't understand how I can mock a variable declared outside my method.

My service looks like this:

```
export class MyService {
    private token: string

    public myMethod(): Promise<boolean> {
        if(!this.token) // do Something
        else // do Something else
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your spec file too?

Comment: I think you can use `spyOnProperty(yourServiceInstance, 'token', 'get').and.returnValue('mockedTokenValue')`.  More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928209/how-to-get-jasmines-spyonproperty-to-work).

Answer (score 0):

Going off what Andrei Gatej said, we can make the token a getter. Now outside classes/contexts can only get the `token` but they cannot write to it. This will help us in mocking it in the unit tests.

Something like this:

```
export class MyService {
    // the _ indicates this is a private variable
    private _token: string;
    get token(): string {
      return this._token;
    }

    // whenever you set your token, do this._token = ....

    public myMethod(): Promise<boolean> {
        if(!this.token) // do Something
        else // do Something else
    }
}
```

Then in your spec file, assuming you have it set up already

```
it('should do the if block', async(done) => {
  spyOnProperty(service, 'token', 'get').and.returnValue(null);
  await service.myMethod();
  await fixture.whenStable();
  // the rest of your assertions
});

it('should do the else block', async(done) => {
  spyOnProperty(service, 'token', 'get').and.returnValue('a token value');
  await service.myMethod();
  await fixture.whenStable();
  // the rest of your assertions
});
```