# jasmine spy on window.innerwidth not getting called

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my Angular 7 project, I want to mock `window.innerWidth` to return a specific value depending on the test case, but it ends up calling the actual window.innerWidth which is the width of the screen where karma is run.

Component.spec.ts:

```
it(`view on small screen`, () => {
  spyOnProperty(window, 'innerWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(1900);
  component.adjustLayout();
});
```

Component.ts:

```
adjustLayout() {
   const width = window.innerWidth;
  ...
}
```

Package versions:

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
"jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148496/how-can-i-spy-on-a-getter-property-using-jasmine
May be some solutions will work for you

Answer (score 0):

For changing the window size and then doing assertions, I find using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-viewport) (karma-viewport) npm package the best where you can specify the width and height of the viewport.

```
viewport.set(1900);
component.adjustLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to provide `window` via injection token.
But if it isn't possible you could use [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) in order to provide proper property definition which can be spied.

a sandbox with the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sunset-uq8lt?file=/src/test.spec.ts

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  // keep SomeComponent and mocks MatTabsModule
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(SomeComponent));

  fit(`view on small screen`, () => {
    const component = MockRender(SomeComponent).point.componentInstance;

    // after that we can spy it
    ngMocks.stub(window, 'innerWidth', 'get');

    spyOnProperty(window, 'innerWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(1900);

    component.adjustLayout();
    expect(component.width).toEqual(1900);
  });
});
```