# Mocking observable getters and setters in jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Lets say I have some state service in angular

```
export class StateService {
 private _someProperty: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    set someProperty(value: boolean) {
       this._someProperty.next(value);
    }

    get someProperty() {
        return this._someProperty.value;
    }

    get someProperty$() {
        return this._someProperty.asObservable();
    }
}
```

How can this be mocked correctly in jasmine? Probably something like this but I dont know how to mock these Behaviour Subject getters and setters.

```
const stateServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService', {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of() from Rxjs will return an observable where the given input value is "observed" immediatly.

so you can

```
spyOnProperty(stateService, 'someProperty$').andReturn(of(false));
```

dont forget to import "of" from rxjs

mocking with jasmine:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169197/9627206
- https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/jasmine-spyon.html

rxjs

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of

Comment: Thank you for response but it seems that you didnt mock that class but use new instance instead. Is it possible with mocked class?

Comment: If the state Service is mocked stubbed or the actual implementation is up to you. It's better to not use the actual implementation in order to write a real unit test of course